# When is specifying generic types for collections necessary?

Tags: java, generics, collections, conventions

The following lines of code each compile (in separate methods, of course):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

Is one of these encouraged over the others? Are there any differences in behavior between these options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` is called diamond operator and it determines the type from Reference variable declaration.

`Recommended is using diamond operator` as this avoids boilerplate or duplicate declaration of type variable as it's clearly visible from the Declaration of variable while allowing a type to default to Object class type if not specified.

All the three above are valid except `List<String> list = new ArrayList();` giving a warning or simply not considered a good practice.

**my thoughts:** `List<String> list = new ArrayList();` could also have been a valid declaration from that perspective but it defaults to array list of Object type (that's how Java is). Precisely:

> if you don't specify a type, it defaults to Object type

Comment: `new ArrayList()` does not default to `Object`, it’s using the *raw type* `List`. That’s why assigning it to `List<String>` is legal, but produces a compiler warning (unless turned off).

Answer (score 2):

This form of declaration is valid for Java up to Version 6

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This form of declaration is valid for Java Version 7+

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And finally for this version, the compiler will generate an unchecked conversion warning but it works:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

For complete explanation refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)